# Auto crop image

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This is a simple camera capture plugin based on cordova that I'm using for basis of this explanation.

I would like to be able to auto-crop the image based on its ROI.

Is it possible to do it on Ionic itself? I have actually done it in my backend via opencv by getting the contour and applying transformation to the image. But due to the client's demand, we're required to find a way to do it on Ionic (front-end)

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Camera) {

  $scope.getPhoto = function() {
    Camera.getPicture().then(function(imageURI) {
      console.log(imageURI);
      $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
    }, function(err) {
      console.err(err);
    }, {
      quality: 75,
      targetWidth: 320,
      targetHeight: 320,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    }); 
  };
```

It's quite simple to just apply a cropper with the many available plugins but is it possible to process the image immediately after camera capture?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `allowEdit : true,` for [cordova camera plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/)

Comment: I do know about cropping the image that way but I would rather not let the user to manually crop the image. If that was the case, I would have used ng-img crop plugin or some other plugin available.